# when I click on custom listview delete button I have getting NullPointerException

Tags: android

When I click on custom listview delete button I am getting NullPointerException

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private ContactListAdapter adapter;
        ListView listView;
        SecondActivity sc;
        Context context;
        private ArrayList<ContactList> contactList;
        private LayoutInflater listItemsLayoutInflater;
        Cursor cursor;
        UserDetailsDB db;
        Bundle dataBundle;
        public ContactListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ContactList> contactList)
        {
        this.contactList=contactList;
        listItemsLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context=context;
        this.adapter=this;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return contactList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public ContactList getItem(int position) 
        {
            return contactList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
                convertView=this.listItemsLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items,parent,false);
                viewHolder.imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                viewHolder.name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_editText);
                viewHolder.edit=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
                viewHolder.delete=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            ContactList contact=contactList.get(position);
            viewHolder.name.setText(contact.getName());
            viewHolder.edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    int id=(int)getItemId(position);
                    id=id+1;
                    dataBundle = new Bundle();
                    dataBundle.putInt("id",id);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,ThirdActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                    context.startActivity(intent);  
                }
            });
            viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    int id=(int)getItemId(position);
                    id=id+1;
                    db.deleteContact(id);
                    db.close();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
        private class ViewHolder
        {
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView name;
            Button edit;
            Button delete;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where initializing `db` object?

Comment: please post the exception itself, including any caused-by sections. (copy the text from `adb logcat`)

Comment: You should put your `setOnClickListener()` inside `if(convertView == null)`. Otherwise, if you've got 100 items in your `ListView`, there'll be 100 click listeners. Compare that to just 1 listener in what I'm suggesting.

Comment: You shouldn't be using ListView, Use RecyclerView instead. It provides much better ViewHolderSupport and you can simply attach the Listener to the Holder. If needed you can bind the actual Item, to the Holder as well. For example if you want to remove the obj from db, you can get its id.